# Are there any references to Tensorflow MNIST example

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

Looking for scientific article references for the network architecture presented in Deep MNIST for Experts tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html)

I have a similar image processing data and I'm looking for a good vanilla architecture, any recommendations?
Currently the best solution for this problem are wavelet transform based solutions

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to look at Deep MNIST for Experts as an example of a good architecture for MNIST or as a scientific baseline. It's more an example of basic Tensorflow building blocks and a nice introduction to convolutional models.

I.e, you should be able to get equal or better results with a model with 5% of the free parameters and less layers.

Comment: Any recommendation on a good book/site/video for better network architectures for Image processing? I'm can really recommend [Stanford's CS 231](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/)    but I'm looking for a more practical approach

Comment: It really depends on your dataset/goal. a) are the images pre-centered/cropped? b) one target per image, or many? c) number of target classes? d) how much training data? e) single images or images from video? f) goal is accuracy, speed, or other? g) compute power available?

Comment: E.g. MNIST is easy on all answers - it only needs 3 layers or so. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html is a good start for harder problems. YOLO is also interesting for some cases. Can you take a pre-trained model and just retrain the upper layer(s)?